# Pimcore - Saving objects with transaction

Tags: php, pimcore

Suppose you have a class named Customer and another class named StreetAddress. A Customer has a multi-href that accepts several StreetAddresses. Suppose now when a Customer registers in the system, it enters a single StreetAddress which will be saved with the Customer object. Now, the critical part is: if we save the Customer first and the StreetAddress later, we may run into a problem if some problem occurs when saving the StreetAddress, the Customer will be on the system without a StreetAddress. So the solution is to make a transaction for saving objects.

I tested the following code:

```
$address = Object_CustomerAddress::create();
$address->setTest('teestt');
$address->setKey('testaddress');

$customer = Object_Customer::create();
$customer->setAddresses(array($address));
$customer->setKey('testcustomer');
$customer->save();
```

This code will save the customer but won't save the address (but also doesn't return any errors). I think this code should make a transaction and save both.

Am I thinking right? Or is there any other way to solve this kind of problem with Pimcore?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't call save() on the CustomerAddress object.

`$address->save()`